# Развёртывание проекта apps script на собственном сервере

Tags: сервер, google-apps-script

Есть таблица с рабочими скриптами в гугл таблицах. При развёртывании оно размещается в облаке гугла, что означает, что запросы будут отправляться с американского IP.
Можно ли развернуть приложение на своём сервере, то бишь на своём компьютере и как?

P.S: Я не супер программист, но при необходимости готов читать документацию и учиться.

Comment: Насколько мне известно - нет. Можете сделать на своем сервере прокладку, которая будет принимать запрос с гугл таблицы, отправлять свой запрос куда надо уже с вашего IP - и вернуть ответ скрипту в гугле.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно - нет. Можете сделать на своем сервере прокладку, которая будет принимать запрос с гугл таблицы, отправлять свой запрос куда надо уже с вашего IP - и возвращать ответ скрипту в гугле.